# Does the set of all limit points respect closure

Tags: real-analysis

Does the following equation hold?
$$A'=[\operatorname{cl}(A)]'$$
where $A'$ is a set of all limit points of $A$ and $\operatorname{cl}(A)$ is closure of $A$.

I am having trouble finding a counterexample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since, $\bar{A}'=\left(A\cup A'\right)'=A'\cup (A')'=A'$ as $A'$ is closed.